# Restart countdwon timer on next button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am working on a bid auction website
i have a count down timer script. its working well on load of window, when i click on restart button it should restart the countdown timer from new value but its not working

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function countDown(hrs,min,sec,gid) { 
  sec--;
  if (sec == -01) {
    sec = 59;
    min = min - 1;
  }
 else {   min = min;  }
 if (min == -01) {
    min = 59;
    hrs = hrs - 1;
  }
 else { hrs = hrs; }
if (sec<=9) { sec = "0" + sec; }
if (hrs<=9) { hrs = "0" + hrs; }
  time = hrs + ":" + (min<=9 ? "0" + min : min) + ":" + sec + "";
if (document.getElementById) { document.getElementById(gid).innerHTML = time; }
  SD=window.setTimeout("countDown("+hrs+","+min+","+sec+",'"+gid+"');", 1000);
if (hrs == '00' && min == '00' && sec == '00') { sec = "00"; window.clearTimeout(SD); }
}

function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}

addLoadEvent(function() {
  countDown(1,0,10,'oneT');
  countDown(0,0,28,'twoT');
  countDown(0,2,15,'threeT');
});
</script>     
<button onclick="countDown(1,0,10,'oneT')">Restart</button>
<div id="oneT" ></div>
<div id="twoT" ></div>
<div id="threeT"></div>
```

Thanks, Ahsan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your onclick event calls countDown without clearing the queued countDown call from setTimeout that was initiated by your original countDown call. This leads to two competing series of calls to countDown. You can see this using your current code when you click "Restart": sometimes the counter will increase and then decrease, as the two competing strings of countDown calls both change the displayed time.

The solution (with minimal code changes), is to store the setTimeout object in a global variable. You can then use clearTimeout to cancel any pending calls to countDown before restarting the timer. This can be done in a new function, restartTimer.

```html
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">

var timers = {};

function countDown(hrs,min,sec,gid) { 
  sec--;
  if (sec == -01) {
    sec = 59;
    min = min - 1;
  }
 else {   min = min;  }
 if (min == -01) {
    min = 59;
    hrs = hrs - 1;
  }
 else { hrs = hrs; }
if (sec<=9) { sec = "0" + sec; }
if (hrs<=9) { hrs = "0" + hrs; }
  time = hrs + ":" + (min<=9 ? "0" + min : min) + ":" + sec + "";
if (document.getElementById) { document.getElementById(gid).innerHTML = time; }
  timers[gid]=window.setTimeout("countDown("+hrs+","+min+","+sec+",'"+gid+"');", 1000);
if (hrs == '00' && min == '00' && sec == '00') { sec = "00"; window.clearTimeout(timers[gid]); }
}

function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}

addLoadEvent(function() {
  countDown(1,0,10,'oneT');
  countDown(0,0,28,'twoT');
  countDown(0,2,15,'threeT');
});

function restartTimer(hrs, min, sec, gid) {
  window.clearTimeout(timers[gid]);
  timers[gid] = countDown(hrs, min, sec, gid);
}

</script>     
<button onclick="restartTimer(1,0,10,'oneT')">Restart</button>
<div id="oneT" ></div>
<div id="twoT" ></div>
<div id="threeT"></div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function resetCountdown() {
    if (SD) {
        clearTimeout(SD);
    }
    countDown(1, 0, 10, 'oneT');
}
</script> 

<button onclick="resetCountdown()">Restart</button>
<div id="oneT" ></div>
```

You need to clear the timeout for every variable that you are using in order to work.